# Google Analytics and Campaign URL Builder

Tags: google-analytics, utm, google-analytics-campaign-builder

I'm trying to track clicks to an amazon product link, I insert that Amazon url to Campaign URL builder. I add the Campaign Source, Medium and a Campaign Name. Of course this Campaign Name is not in my GA because I want to create that campaign now. After having the url built and going to visit that url, the campaign does not show up on GA.

My questions are,
Can you add UTM parameters to any url?
Do you have to create a campaign using Campaign Manager before using Campaign URL Builder?

Answer (score 1):

For you to see the campaign data, you must be linking to a site where you have access to the GA property. Because of this, it is really meant for you to measure marketing tactics driving traffic driving to your own site. Because you're driving to Amazon, you won't see stats in GA, since I assume you don't have access to Amazon's GA property (I don't even know if they use GA).

To answer your question:
You can add campaign parameter to any URL, it is just that you won't see the data or the data won't be collected unless you have access to the GA property of the sites you're driving to.

You don't have to create a campaign in the campaign manager before using a URL builder.

If you really want to track clicks to Amazon product links, you can either put event/click tracking through GA on your website OR use a URL shortening service like bitly to track the amount of clicks going through.